# include downcase in if statement for ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to compare if one path is included in the other and I don't care about case sensitivity, is this a right thinking:

```
if row[0].to_s.downcase != "" && File.read(commit_file).include?(row[0].downcase)
        .
        .
        .       
end
```

thnx!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.read` returns the content of the file as a String. So, to achieve what you want, you would need to convert both Strings you're working with to lowercase. You can achieve it by:

```
if row[0].to_s != "" && File.read(commit_file).downcase.include?(row[0].to_s.downcase)
```

Comment: slightly related, I believe the process is called normalising.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`casecmp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-casecmp), it does exactly what you need..one check will do the trick..

```
if File.read(commit_file).casecmp(row[0].to_s).zero?
```